# PHP parse XML / String Response from CDN Flush API

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

I am making a request to a CDN API which flushes the cache for specific items. I am trying to parse the response correctly, but the response is not only returned (from how I can see it) incorrectly, but I am struggling to parse such a large amount of information. My aim is to get a list of unsuccessful flushes from the response, along with any error codes.

**This is the kind of URL that you run for their API to process the request:**

`https://openapi.us.cdnetworks.com/OpenAPI/services/CachePurgeAPI/executeCachePurge?userId=***&password=***&purgeUriList=http://urlhere.com?param1=here&param2=here&purgeUriList=http:://url2here.com?param1=here`

The documentation states that the response is in XML. Which it IS when you type the address into the browser. But performing a request from PHP brings back something that isn't XML.

**It *should* look like this:**

[image]

**But what I actually get back is this:**

`000REQUEST ACCEPTEDhttp://cdn.oursite.com/blah.php?alt=1&cid=6291&campaign=126400&width=25010REQUEST ACCEPTEDhttp://cdn.oursite.co.uk/blah.php?alt=1&cid=6292&campaign=126401&width=250122';`

Now that's just an example of two *successful* flushes. The API docs show a load of extra errors that could be returned:

`0: Successful; 2: Successful only in some URLs; 999: Temporary Error; 194 Too many URLs`

I don't want to have to parse the string for each individual response. The first part returned is a resultCode, the second a totalURLNum, third successes, fourth fails, and then a result list containing even more information.

**My initial PHP code to retrieve the string:**

A simple file_get_contents request.

`$result = file_get_contents(urlencode($url));`

**Then I got some RED TEXT back!!!**

I used cURL with `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` set to false:

`$aData = curl_exec($rData);`

and this returned red text:

`string '<ns:executeCachePurgeResponse xmlns:ns="http://control.webif.server.openapi.cdnetworks.com"><ns:return xmlns:ax21="http://cachepurge.purge.response.server.openapi.cdnetworks.com/xsd" type="com.cdnetworks.openapi.server.response.purge.cachepurge.CachePurge"><ax21:failureURLNum>2</ax21:failureURLNum><ax21:resultCode>2</ax21:resultCode>(etc)(etc) (length=1678)`

**Tried using SimpleXML:**

So I tried using simplexml on this. I've tried:

`$xml = simplexml_load_string($aData);`

also

`$properties = $xml->xpath('//Property');`

and I've tried using SimpleXML to load the initial file:

`$result = simplexml_load_file($url)`

How can I go about parsing this? It's clear I'm not getting back XML like I want to, and the string is going to be a nightmare to parse through.

**What I'm currently up to:**

I ran the following PHP on the cURL output.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$dom->loadXML($aData);
$dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $dom->saveXml();
```

This gave me a slightly more formatted output, but it's **still** not XML so not easy to parse!:

`2 2 9999 Check your input. If it's not wrong, contact us please. http://cdn.whatever.co.uk/blah.php?alt=1&cid=6291&campaign=126400&width=250 0 0 REQUEST ACCEPTED http://cdn.whatever.co.uk/blah.php?alt=1&cid=6292&campaign=126401&width=250 1 9999 Check your input. If it's not wrong, contact us please. http://cdn.whatever.co.uk/blah.php?alt=1&cid=6291&campaign=126400&width=250 0 1 3`

Using `<pre>` on either side of the XML, viewing the source, and then putting the code into an XML validator returns that it is false xml.

Namespaces CAN be retrieved, but that's as far as grabbing data from the XML can go. The XML is not valid, the dev team are working on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'XML' returned is not valid if it cannot be handled properly by simplexml.

Try using an xml validator to make sure that you are indeed trying to parse valid xml.

Comment: From the question, it's clear that the questioner is not getting errors from the XML parser, they are just attempting to echo back the parsed XML and not understanding what they are looking at.

Comment: After trying numerous attempts to use the XML returned, it turns out it's not actually valid XML, so it can't be searched through using typical libraries. I understand what I am looking at with XML. My answer does not deserve a downvote.

Comment: Nothing in the question, apart from the recent edit, suggested any error other than you attempting to use a web browser to display raw XML. There are no samples of XML, and no error messages, and you repeatedly refer to "red text" - a string of text has no colour, so this strongly suggested you were not looking at the real response. Your last example, using DOM functions, seemed to suggest the parsing was successful.

Comment: The parsing was unsuccessful because the XML returned by their API is not valid. This has been confirmed by their dev team and is currently being fixed. The XML was being displayed for debugging purposes, the final script will not ever show the XML. Does this clarify enough for you? Also the 'red text' was an attempt at humour - I usually don't receive overly critical responses for such things.

Comment: In which case perhaps I should have downvoted the question instead of the answer, as none of the information given would have allowed us to help you (too late now, my vote on the answer is "locked in" according to the site). The mentions of "red text" still make no sense to me; are they a reference to an error message? Why did you not tell us what the message was? Why does the example output ending `(etc)(etc) (length=1678)` show actual XML, but the others a stripped-tag version of it?

Comment: It was made quite clear that my intention was to grab XML from a source. I documented my attempts to read this XML using the most commonly used methods; including `SimpleXML`; This being the correct method for parsing the XML. My attempts were also made clear. It then turned out that the XML received wasn't valid. The failure output ending `(etc) (etc) (length=1678)` is partial XML and the errors in that would not have helped any other developers answer my question - the errors being specific to the API and NOT the output. My formatted end answer is the best anyone could do with invalid XML.

Comment: You documented your attempts, but not what errors you were encountering - you mentioned trying SimpleXML, but gave no indication of why you abandoned that route. If the XML is invalid, then a better sample of the raw data might have helped reveal that. The best anyone could do with invalid XML is paste the invalid XML - pasting it with all the tags stripped out is useful to exactly nobody.

Comment: The simple case of invalid XML is something that I was meant to discover on my own. Pasting the whole of the XML (1678, remember?) would have filled up a lot of space on the page. It was to be assumed the XML was valid, and therefore `Simple XML` usage was the correct route to take. As I didn't give outputs of this route, they clearly returned false.

Comment: I also didn't abandon the updates and regularly documented my methods, so my question wouldn't have deserved a -1. If you felt this, you should have considered leaving it neutral, as a -1 indicates absolutely nothing positive with the question.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're doing is trying to echo the XML directly to the browser. If you do that, the browser will assume it's HTML, and any XML tags will be invisible, so you'll just see the text in between.

Try one of the following:

- Escape the XML with HTML entities: `echo htmlspecialchars($response)`
- View Source in your browser
- Tell the browser you're giving it XML, not HTML: `header('Content-Type: text/xml');`